# Prestashop 1.6: reuse administration product list page in my own module

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I want to reuse the product list view in the administration of the products  (same table style)in my module page that I already created.
[image: table style wanted]
I get to retrieve the products by cons I can not display them in the same way.
I am looking for a solution not to redo all the work manually
My controller code:

```
 $products = Product::getProducts($this->context->language->id, 0, 100,'name','asc');
$products_all = Product::getProductsProperties($this->context->language->id, $products);
$this->smarty->assign('products_all',$products_all);
```

Comment: you need the tpl view to that page

Answer (score 0):

This page is generated in AdminProductsController by HelperList. So basically, you could copy / paste all the concerned lines in your own module. There's no tpl.